# Matlab: Incorrect estimates returned by fminsearch

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, parameters, fminsearch

I am trying to maximize a log-likelihood function of an autoregressive process (AR(1))

`ERS(t) = 1+ 0.3*ERS(t-1) + epsilon(t)` 
in order to estimate the parameters. Maximizing the log -likelihood involves finding the derivatives and so I thought of using fminsearch. I have changed the sign of the log likelihood in the implementation. The actual log-likelihood is presented below.

[image: Log likelihood]
 where the set of parameters

```
theta = {rho1 = c = 1, rho2 = 0.3 and rho3 = variance of the noise sigma2_epsilon}
```

`fminsearch` returns

```
0.808518411146547
1.00012215100964
1.13507247075777
```

which are incorrect. On the other hand, I checked with Least Square and the Least square estimates are close to the true parameters. In the implementation I have ignored the constant terms of the log-likelihood. Can somebody please help in rectifying the code and where I am going wrong? Thank you.
The code

```
clc
clear all
global ERS
var_eps = 1;
epsilon = sqrt(var_eps)*randn(5000,1); % Gaussian signal exciting the AR model
theta0 = ones(3,1);
ERS(1) = 0.0;
for t= 2:5000
ERS(t)= 1+ 0.3*ERS(t-1) + epsilon(t-1); %AR(1) model
end
[theta,opt] = fminsearch(@(theta) ll_AR1(theta,ERS),theta0);

function L2 = ll_AR1(theta,Y)
rho0 = theta(1);
rho1 = theta(2);
sigma2_epsilon = theta(3);
T= size(Y,1);
%changed sign
L1 = 0.5*(sigma2_epsilon)^(-1)*(Y(2:end) - rho0 - rho1*(Y(1:end-1))).^2;
L2 = 0.5*log(sigma2_epsilon/(1-rho1.^2)) +0.5*(sigma2_epsilon)^(-1)*(1-rho1.^2)*(Y(1)- (rho0/(1-rho1))).^2 + 0.5*(T-1)*log(sigma2_epsilon) + sum(L1) ; % the log-likelihood function
end
```

Comment: You have better luck on the DSP site: dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: I have asked the Question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124462/matlab-incorrect-estimates-from-log-likelihood

Comment: Have you tried to define the initial value and the limits for your parameters?

Comment: It looks like you should be able to derive the derivative of L1 and L2. I'd suggest finding that and then minimizing its squared value. That should give you a convex cost function that tells you where the derivative goes to zero, which would be critical point and, presumably, the point where the function reaches its maximum value.

Comment: (Another question to which substantial destructive edits were applied after an answer came in, rolled back again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem does not seem to be [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function). This means `fminsearch` will find a local minimum rather than a global minimum, and thus your result will be dependent on your initial estimation. You can check this by altering your `theta0` value to for example

```
theta0 = 0.99*ones(3,1);
```

Which yields completely different results.

One way of working around this problem is using a [Monte Carlo method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), which basically means you run the simulation over and over again for different initial conditions and select the result that yields the largest function value (along with its optimization parameter set theta). The more simulations you run, the more likely you are to find the 'true' optimum, although this is not a guaranteed outcome.

Comment: SO, what other technique apart from fminsearch should I use for solving likelihood when the problem has multiple solutions?

Comment: Try to use a Monte Carlo method (or other similar methods).

Comment: I've added the Monte Carlo method to my answer

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Would it be possible if you could just put up a skeleton code for the above program to demonstrate Monte Carlo? I can visualize how to apply for one unknown parameter, but how would it work for a vector of unknown parameters? Shall appreciate your effort and time.